# Values of Constants for an Exponentially Decaying General Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a doubt about the following question:

For the differential equation with constant coefficients
$$y''  +  by'  +  cy  =  0 $$

the general solution $y(x)$ approaches zero as $x$ approaches $\infty$ if

(a) $b \gt 0, c \gt 0 $

(b) $b \gt 0, c \lt 0 $

(c) $b \lt 0, c \gt 0 $

(d) $b \lt 0, c \lt 0 $

*Doubt:*
On solving the differential equation by forming the auxiliary equation, I get the general solution (assuming $\sqrt{b^2-4c} \gt 0$) as: $$y=c_{1}e^{x{\frac{-b + \sqrt{b^2 - 4c}}{2}}} + c_{2}e^{x{\frac{-b - \sqrt{b^2 - 4c}}{2}}}$$

I tried doing $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} y$, which equated to zero (I might be stupid by doing so). But I have no idea on answering the actual question. I would appreciate if someone could help me and let me know if I am missing anything out.

**Edit 1**: The solution according to the answer key is (a).

Comment: If the roots of the characteristic equation are real:  are they both positive, both negative of one of each?  What happens if the roots are complex?  What happens in each of those cases?

Comment: Well, to be honest, I have no idea on what happens in those cases. I considered all the cases: distinct-real (discriminant $D \gt 0 $), repeated ( $D = 0$) and complex ($D \lt 0$) and the limit condition (i.e. limx→∞y = 0) applies in all the cases.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution to your differential equation is $$y= C_1e^{\lambda_1x}+ C_2e^{\lambda_2x}$$ where $\lambda _1$ and $\lambda_2$  are roots of $$\lambda ^2 +b\lambda +c =0$$

Note that the sum of your eigenvalues is $\lambda _1+ \lambda _2=-b$ and the product is $\lambda _1\lambda _2=c$

For both eigenvalues to be negative you need $b>0$ and $c>0$ that is case (a)

Comment: The answer is correct as per the key. But we haven't covered the method of using eigenvalues in differential equations, although I did learn it in my linear algebra class. So, I would appreciate if you could explain it briefly.

Comment: Mohammed +1 for your nice answer ....in your comment you forgot the variable $$y=C_1 e^{\lambda _1x} + C_2 e^{\lambda _2x}$$

Comment: @Isham Thanks for the comment. You are correct, we need the independent variable there. Thanks again.

Comment: @PranavDinesh The roots of the polynomial $λ^2+bλ+c=0$ are called eigenvalues. The general solution to your differential equation is the $y=C_1e^{λ_1x}+C_2e^{λ_2 x}$You want both eigenvalues to be negative so the solution to approaches zero.

Answer (score 1):

According to your solution,

$$
C_1e^{\frac x2(-b+\sqrt{b^2-4c})}+C_2e^{\frac x2(-b-\sqrt{b^2-4c})}
$$

If

a) we have $-b < 0\;$ and $\sqrt{b^2-4c} < b\;$ with $y$ exponentially decaying. For $c \le \frac{b^2}{4}\;$ and if $c > \frac{b^2}{4}\;$ then we will have 
$$
y =  e^{-\frac{bx}{2}}\left(C_1\cos\omega t + C_2\sin\omega t\right)
$$
hence $b > 0, c > 0\;\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to\infty} = 0$

b) If $b > 0, c < 0\Rightarrow \sqrt{b^2-4c} > b$ and then the exponential $e^{(-\frac{b}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4c}}{2})x}$ grows positively hence $b > 0, c < 0\;\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to\infty} = \pm\infty$

c)
If $b < 0$ then independent of the $c$ value, we will have one of the exponential positive hence $b < 0, c > 0\;\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to\infty} = \pm\infty$

d) This item is treated in c) hence $b < 0, c < 0\;\Rightarrow \lim_{x\to\infty} = \pm\infty$